# Twitter Bootstrap button js not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I can't seem to get the button states to change.

I am copying the js from http://jsfiddle.net/YCst4/1/ and I'm not getting a response. It's like I don't have jQuery loaded, but I have bootstrap.min.js loaded in my header. I don't have any problems with other javascript on the page.

This is what I have in my Codeigniter view:

```
<script>
$('#button').button();

$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
});
</script>

<button class="btn" id="button" type="button" data-text-loading="Loading...">Press Me</button>
```

Any ideas on what's causing this? is bootstrap-button.js not a part of the bootstrap.min.js that comes with Bootstrap?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

EDIT:

When I view-source the page, I can see the bootstrap.min.js loaded in the header view, and I can click on it to see it's source, so the path is correct. However, the button js code only works when I repeat `<script src="http://site.dev/assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in the actual content view itself.

I have the jQuery loaded a line above the bootstrap.min.js and the jQuery elements in the same view as the button work perfectly. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js loading after bootstrap.min.js. Apparently there's some conflict.

Comment: The actual issue is bootstrap.js requires jQuery. There is jQuery code in bootstrap.js so that is why jquery has to be imported first. It has nothing to do with conflicts.

Answer (score 9):

You need to put you code in a document ready function so that it will run after the page is ready, not before.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').button();

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
  });  
});
```

JS Fiddle seems to do this automatically for you, which is why it works there.

Comment: Still no luck :/ I put exactly what you wrote along with the button in a view with nothing else, and it's state doesn't change.

Comment: I have no experience with code igniter, but I would confirm that the javascript is indeed getting run and that it is successfully binding the button.

Comment: "It's like I don't have jQuery loaded, but I have bootstrap.min.js loaded in my header." I'm confused, do you have JQuery loaded? You have to load it separately from bootstrap.min.js, that only loads the bootstrap plugins

Comment: lol, ya, I have jQuery loaded. I have other jQuery on the page that is working fine too. I'm going to load it somewhere outside of CI and see if it helps.

Comment: Updated the OP with the results.

Comment: Well I would look for errors with Firebug or a similar tool, just to make sure everything is working right. If you can't find anything there, maybe try including that button.js separately? I remember having a problem with bootstrap.js once where I needed to include the bootstrap-tabs js separately.

Comment: I solved it. Ended up just being a conflict with jQuery UI. Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind a click to the button before the button is part of the DOM. Put your stuff in the document ready function and you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

For javascript newbies like me: you also need to load jQuery **before** you define `$('#button').click()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Here are some things that might help you:

1. Are you loading your js files in the necessary order. The listed order (as script tags) MUST be in the correct (dependency-based) order like so:

   ```
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="button_app.js."></script>
   ```
2. Are you using local or remote css/js files? If you're using remote ones. Check if any of them reference github. If they look like this:

   ```
   <script src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
   ```

   they won't work. Chrome will throw a mime type error.